# Perl array iteration error - found error but why?

Tags: arrays, perl, error-handling, iteration

I have actually caught my offending error in Windows 7 perl 5 v20.  However, I am very interested into why.  I must be messing with the internal iteration somehow, but I wish to know why/how so I may avoid this!  If I mask the part labeled below as offending, I see that I can find the name of interest.  Otherwise, it never finds it!

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hashofhashes;
my @headers;
my ($i, $temp, $flag)=0;
open FILE, '<', 'C:\direction\to\file.txt' or die $!;
while ( $line = <FILE> ) {
    $line =~ /^(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)\t/;
    $hashofhashes{$1}{$2} = $3; # a bit more logic, but this is the idea behind it
    push @headers, $1;
}
close FILE;
open SAVE,  '>', 'C:\somewhere\important\savefile.txt'  or die $!;
open SAVED, '>', 'C:\somewhere\important\savefileD.txt' or die $!;
print SAVE  "Name";
print SAVED "Name";
for ( $i = 0; $i < scalar @headers; $i++ ) {
    print SAVE "\tAverage\tlog2\tfold (loss/normal) $headers[$i]\tp-value $headers[$i]";
    print SAVED "\tAverage\tlog2\fold (gain/normal) $headers[$i]\tp-value $headers[$i]";
    $temp++;
    print "$temp: $headers[$i]\n";  # visual QC on prompt
    if ($headers[$i] eq 'Joe') {
        print "FOUND IT!!!  $headers[$i]\n"; 
        <STDIN>; 
        $flag = 1;
    }
    if ($temp == 100) {
        print "Have done " . $i++ . " of ". scalar @headers . "\n"; 
        $temp = 0;  # this is the offending line!!!
    }
    print SAVE "\n"; 
    print SAVED "\n";
    unless ($flag) {
        print "sorry bud!\n";
        die;
    }
}
```

The flag idea is new in the code here, but the logic followed in for loop is exact.  QCing reports that there are 2123 different elements stored in the header and 20 are lost.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You're manually incrementing `$i` every 100 times through the loop, so it throws away (skips) every 100th item.

Comment: @JimDavis you should make that an answer

Comment: Also, the line `my ($i, $temp, $flag)=0;` is not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: Thanks @JimDavis, it looks like a good face palm is in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something more like this:

```
use v5.10;

open my $save,   '>', 'C:\somewhere\important\savefile.txt' or die $!;
open my $saved,  '>', 'C:\somewhere\important\savefileD.txt' or die $!;
print { $save }  "Name";
print { $saved } "Name";

open my $fh, '<', 'C:\direction\to\file.txt' or die $!;

my $found = 0;
while( my $line = <FILE> ){
    my( $name, $second, $last ) = $line =~ /^(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*?)\t/;

    if( $name eq 'Joe' ) {
        say "Found it on line $.!";
        <STDIN>;
        $found++;
        }

    say "Processed $. lines" unless $. % 100;
    print { $save } "\tAverage\tlog2\tfold (loss/normal) $name\tp-value $headers[$i]";
    print { $saved } "\tAverage\tlog2\fold (gain/normal) $name\tp-value $headers[$i]";
    }
close $fh;

say "Did not find it!" unless $found;
```

It looks like you are going through the data line-by-line, so you don't need to load up an array that you'll go through element-by-element later. Just do it all in the same loop.

I think you're using `$temp` to output a progress message every 100 elements. Perl has a built-in line counter in `$.` so you can use that. You can use the modulus operator `%` to test if it's divisible by 100. If it is (so, no remainder), output your progress message. You don't need to reset `$temp` because 200, 300, and so on are still divisible by 100.

In your code, you were incrementing `$i` in the `for` and in the conditional where you were fooling with `$temp`. Every 100 elements, you'd increment `$i` then the `for` would do it again before the next iteration. You were then skipping every 100th line.

I know what you are doing is more complicated and that hash probably does something, but you can adjust this idea to fit what you are doing.

Lastly, if you want other people to want to help, help them with the liberal use of vertical whitespace to group statements into paragraphs and horizontal whitespace to align common structures. :)